# UIView in tableViewCell crash issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have created a UIView in tableViewCell and set UIView contraints 5 from all side,
but when I try to change its backgroud color or getting its frame facing crash

**Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value**

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var viewCell: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

     func designCell(data:[String:Any]){
        self.viewCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow //getting crash
    }
}
```

Comment: which line did you faced an error?

Comment: Hi Khalid, two things: 1) Did you connect the viewCell in the tableview cell and 2) did you define your tableview cell? If any of them are not true, you have a nil.

Comment: 1).Did you connect the viewCell in the tableview cell : Yes
2).did you define your tableview cell: Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are facing means that you forgot to connect the `viewCell` outlet in storyboard. Open your storyboard and make sure the outlet is connected to the desired `viewCell`.